# Laravel withPivot is not returning pivot extra fields

Tags: php, laravel

I have Two models called Product and Store
In Store model i have this codes:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'product_store')->withPivot('price','qty','is_block');
    }

    public function scopeDistance($query, $latitude, $longitude, $distance, $columns = ['*'])
    {

        return $query->select($columns)
            ->selectRaw('( 6372.795477598 * acos( cos( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) *
            cos( radians(latitude) ) *
            cos( radians(longitude) - radians(' . $longitude . ') ) +
            sin( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) *
            sin( radians(latitude) ) ) )
            AS distance')
            ->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
    }
```

In Product model i have this code:

```
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'product_store', 'product_id', 'store_id')->withPivot('price', 'qty', 'is_block');
    }

 protected $with = ['brand', 'category', 'likes','store'];
```

And i have a resource for Product with this code:

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        $user = auth('api')->user();
        ($store_id = \App\Models\Store::distance($user->addresses()->first()->latitude,$user->addresses()->first()->longitude,10)->first());
        $store = \App\Models\Store::find($store_id);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'price' => $this->price,
//            'real_price' => isset($store) ? $store->pivot->price : $this->pivot->price,
            'category_id' => $this->category_id,
            'viewed' => $this->viewed,
            'is_active' => $this->is_active,
            'qty_change' => $this->qty_change,
            'limit' => $this->limit,
            'images' => $this->images,
            'brand_id' => $this->brand_id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            'store' => $store ,
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'category' => $this->category,
            'likes' => $this->likes,
            'liked' => auth('api')->check() ? ((DB::table('wish_lists')->where('product_id', $this->id)->where('user_id', $user->id)->first()) ? 1 : 0) : 0
        ];
    }

    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'store' => $this->store[0] ?? null,
                'category' => $this->category,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

So when i use  `$store = \App\Models\Store::find($store_id);` it should return a `pivot` in my store relation but it is not doing this. Please help me to solve it

Thank you in advance

Comment: You've wrapped the arguments to `withPivot` in an array on one of your models.

Comment: BTW wrapping your code to prevent long lines helps you spot mistakes like this more easily.

Comment: @miken32 can you explain your meaning in one answer? i did not get it

Comment: I can't be any clearer. In `Store::products()` you've wrapped your arguments to `withPivot()` in an array.

Comment: @miken32 hmmm i changed it but nothing changed in result

Comment: You're also not requesting the `products` relationship to be eager loaded.

Comment: @miken32 Yes i changed it because i need to get products from the nearest store to user.... Do you have solution?

Comment: dose my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load the pivot when you retrieve the store, you have to eager load it.

in `Store.php` Model:

```
protected $with = ['products'];
```

it seems this lines:

```
($store_id = \App\Models\Store::distance($user->addresses()->first()->latitude,$user->addresses()->first()->longitude,10)->first());
```

is returning Store Model and should be change :

```
$store = \App\Models\Store::distance($user->addresses()->first()->latitude,$user->addresses()->first()->longitude,10)->first();
```